# Reading double values from a file

Tags: java

I'm trying to read some numbers (double) from a file and store them in an ArrayList and an array (yes, I need both) with the code below:

```
try {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\\s*\\n");

    while(scan.hasNextDouble())
    {
        tmp.add(scan.nextDouble());
    }

    Double[][] tmp2 = new Double[tmp.size()/2][2];
    int tmp3 = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < tmp.size()/2; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            tmp2[i][j] = tmp.get(tmp3);
            tmp3++;
        }
    }

} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

The file I'm trying to read is:

```
0.0 0.0
0.023 0.023
0.05 0.05
0.2 0.2
0.5 0.5
0.8 0.8
0.950 0.950
0.977 0.977
1.0 1.0
```

But well my code doesn't work, the hasNextDouble() function doesn't find anything, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: ok so I edited the source a bit (changed from Object[][] to Double[][]) and added inserting values into the array after they were inserted into the ArrayList, but it still doesn't work - the 'while' loop isn't executed a single time.

Comment: Yeah I tried with both "." and "," but neither worked.

Comment: I do believe there's something wrong with what you're doing with `tmp`. What is its type, and what's in it before your code starts?

Comment: List<Double> tmp = new ArrayList<Double>();

But I think it's not it, I just think the scan.hasNextDouble() returns false always.

Comment: Please go read a decent book on variable naming and coding standards. Do you really think anybody (even yourself after a few weeks) will understand tmp, tmp2, tmp3?

Comment: It is, as the name suggests, a temporary variable, which is used only there. Only better name would be: "aTemporaryArrayWhichStoresDataFromTheFileWhichThenWillBePutIntoAJTable".

Comment: You sure Scanner is reading the correct file?

Comment: @Zenzen: that's a coding horror, mate. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried reducing the code down to only test the Scanner by itself.  The following code works with your data file:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan;
    File file = new File("resources\\scannertester\\data.txt");
    try {
        scan = new Scanner(file);

        while(scan.hasNextDouble())
        {
            System.out.println( scan.nextDouble() );
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I got the following (expected) output:

```
0.0
0.0
0.023
0.023
0.05
0.05
0.2
0.2
0.5
0.5
0.8
0.8
0.95
0.95
0.977
0.977
1.0
1.0
```

Try this to make sure you're referencing the correct file.

Comment: Added the delimiter, but nothing changed. I added two System.out.println to see what's wrong, the one right before "while" is ok, but the one in the while loop doesn't print.

Comment: @Bill: I have trouble believing that. I just ran the code with no change and Scanner had no trouble reading the input.

Comment: sho nuff. I wrapped it into a main() and prepended definitions for tmp and file.

Comment: Okay, that's the part I'm trying to work out.  I just saw your comment to the question.

Comment: I don't know why (will check it later), but it works, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (not working scanner) and the solution seems to be surprisingly easy.
You just need to set a locale for it.

```
  // use US locale to be able to identify doubles in the string
  scanner.useLocale(Locale.US);
```

taken from here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextdouble.htm

Answer (score 1):

Below is my rendition of your code, adapted to make it run. It immediately explodes with an array indexing exceptions.

So: Can you give us a little more framework? What's different from what I did?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Zenzen {

   private static ArrayList<Double> tmp = new ArrayList<Double>();

   private static File file = new File("Zenzen.dat");

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner scan;
      try {
         scan = new Scanner(file);
         Object[][] tmp2 = new Object[tmp.size() / 2][2];
         int tmp3 = 0;

         while (scan.hasNextDouble()) {
            tmp.add(scan.nextDouble());
            System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(tmp.toArray())); // debug print
            for (int i = 0; i < tmp.size() / 2; i++) {
               for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                  tmp2[i][j] = tmp.get(tmp3);
                  tmp3++;
               }
            }
         }

      } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
         fnfe.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

---

```
[0.0]
[0.0, 0.0]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at Zenzen.main(Zenzen.java:26)
```

Comment: Oh yeah I declared the tmp2 array too early, I changed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the delimiter first:

```
scan.useDelimiter("\\s+");
```

[JavaDoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)