# load doubles into an arrayList

Tags: java

I have a text file with a list of doubles.  The first value of the line is the x value and the second value is the y value.

```
  103.0 274.0
  133.0 383.0
  342.0 250.0
  204.0 126.0
  177.0 357.0
  ...
```

How can I read these values and load them into an array list?

```
  ArrayList<Point> store = new ArrayList<Point>();


                  File file = fc.getSelectedFile();

               StringBuilder all = new StringBuilder();

               BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(file));
               String input = null;
               while ((input = reader.readLine()) != null)
               {
                 String a =  all.append(input+"\n").toString();

                 String[] hold = a.split(" ");

                double x =  Double.parseDouble(hold[0]);
                int aa = (int)(x);
                double y = Double.parseDouble(hold[1]);
                int bb = (int)(y);

                store.add(new Point(aa, bb));
                }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855753/reading-double-values-from-a-file

Comment: please take a bit more care when formatting your code (this forum can't handle tabs smoothly, especially not when mixed with spaces - as you can see :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1: Get an input stream of the file.
2: read line by line using readLine() method
3: split the string by SPACE using split() method of String class
4: the String array you got has two elements now.
5: Double.parseDouble(array[0]) and Double.parseDouble(array[1]) are value of x and y
6: store these values into the corresponding values of Point object
7: add that point object to ArrayList.
8: Done
```

Comment: Well I worked on it a bit.  I can't get it to work correctly. See above.

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "178.0
306.0"  The first line of the file is: 349.0 178.0 and the second line of the file is: 306.0 159.0

Comment: @chief instead of taking a StringBuilder appending it and reconverting toString, try using the value input only. I mean in the while loop, remove the first line and in the 2nd line instead of a.split use input.split.

Comment: @chief while ((input = reader.readLine()) != null)
               {

                 String[] hold = input.split(" ");

                double x =  Double.parseDouble(hold[0]);
                int aa = (int)(x);
                double y = Double.parseDouble(hold[1]);
                int bb = (int)(y);

                store.add(new Point(aa, bb));
                }

Comment: Thanks.  It is now taking the file and loading the data into the arrayList.

Comment: @chief previously your problem was because of the append of \n character

Answer (score 1):

using java Scanner and nextDouble()

Scanner is use to read file and
parameter nextDouble() is data type in read file

Answer (score 0):

You can use resource bundle in java.