# In Java, read matrix with named rows and named columns from CSV

Tags: java, matrix

I have a CSV file which contains a matrix of correlation coefficients between a set of objects (in the example below it is four objects u101, u102, u103, u104). The files uses the object names as row names and column names like so:

```
        u101,   u102,   u103,   u104
u101,   1.0,    0.2,    0.1,    0.4
u102,   0.2,    1.0,    0.5,    0.8
u103,   0.1,    0.5,    1.0,    0.9
u104,   0.4,    0.8,    0.9,    1.0
```

What I now need to do is: read the CSV file into some matrix format in Java such that I can access the correlation coefficients by name. Basically, I need to implement a function:

```
double getValue(String arg0, String arg1) {
    […]
}
```

When invoked with

```
getValue("u101", "u104")
```

the function should then return 0.4.

How can I do that?

Comment: [Read 2D array from file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769976/reading-2-d-array-from-a-file) (you'll probably want to use `next` for row/col names and `nextDouble` for cells). Convert String to row/col index - `Map<String, Integer>`. If the naming for row/col `i` is always `u(101+i)`, then you can simply `substring` and `parseInt`.

Answer (score 1):

You would need 2 maps and a 2 dimensional array (or arraylist).

- 1st map should contain the col name as the key and the col position as value i.e. ('u101', 0), ('u102', 1) etc
- 2nd map should contain the row name as the key and the row postion as value
- The 2d array should have the data, i.e. the numbers themselves

So when you get a call to your method, you do like

```
return myArray[rowmap.get('rowname')][colmap.get('colname')];
```

Answer (score 0):

To read doubles from a file: [Reading double values from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855753/reading-double-values-from-a-file)

Then store the values you read in a HashMap of doubles. Construct the hashmap keys using both the row and column name. To access the element at u102, u103 do:

```
hashmap.put("u102-u103", 0.5);
x = hashmap.get("u102-u103");
```

Comment: It may help to say a HashMap of what exactly you're suggesting.